# Pstricks errors on Mac texlive 2020

Tags: pstricks

As soon as I load pstricks, everything goes haywire. Similarly to a previously asked question, with the very minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
Here we go.
\end{document}
```

this shows up before the beginning of the document:

```
tx@Dict begin Rand end¡randomgraygray tx@Dict begin Rand end¡gray tx@Dict begin Rand end¡randomgray
```

I deleted all texlive installations and started with a fresh install of MacTex 2020 + Ghostscript 9.50 then updated all packages using Tex Live Utility, but no joy. It does not matter what engine I use.

```
### This is /Library/TeX/texbin/simpdftex, Version 20180924
### /Library/TeX/texbin/latex cycloid.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cycloid.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/Users/Bridget/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/Users/Bridget/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/graphics/dvips.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v3.01  <2020/09/18> (tvz,hv)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con)
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: LaTeX
 Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \@temptokena 
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Undef
ined control sequence.
<argument> ...v \@temptokena \expandafter {\@@col 
                                                  }\csname color@\@@cls \exp...
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.662  }
        
Runaway argument?
tx@Dict begin Rand Rand Rand end\p@ <\z@ 0\@@ \@@drv \ifx \@@cls \@empty \ETC.
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:667: Parag
raph ended before \c@lor@@rgb was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.667 
      
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file cycloid.aux.
[1] (./cycloid.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 662 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 5 was incomplete)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on cycloid.dvi (1 page, 916 bytes).
SyncTeX written on cycloid.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on cycloid.log.
### WARNING: TeX returned non zero exit status 
### /Library/TeX/texbin/dvips -R -Poutline  -o /tmp/altpdflatex.75590-1612997306/cycloid.ps cycloid.dvi
This is dvips(k) 2020.1 Copyright 2020 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2021.02.10:1448' -> /tmp/altpdflatex.75590-1612997306/cycloid.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
[1] 
### ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5  /tmp/altpdflatex.75590-1612997306/cycloid.ps /tmp/altpdflatex.75590-1612997306/cycloid.pdf


%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER

### Copying/moving pdf file /tmp/altpdflatex.75590-1612997306/cycloid.pdf to cycloid.pdf
### Succesfully generated cycloid.dvi and cycloid.pdf
```

Comment: your problem description is hard to understand it surely makes a difference which engine you use. pstricks does not work at all with pdflatex or luatex,  there is no reason why you should not be able to post the log you get using latex in a code block.

Comment: Okay, it let me post the log now - maybe because I am a new user, it did not let me before. About the engine: I am aware of the problem with pdflatex and have never used luatex, but it does not work with latex or xelatex.

Comment: The log  says you compiled with pdflatex, not xelatex

Comment: well that's odd I have same latex same pstricks and no error (the error is the important thing, what output you get after an error is sort of arbitrary)

Comment: what output do you get from `kpsewhich --all --engine pdftex latex.fmt`

Comment: @Bernard no it shows format=latex not format=pdflatex

Comment: *what is this* `(/Users/Bridget/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/xcolor/xcolor.sty`  you have local xcolor and dvips.def masking the standard one. That can not end well...

Comment: @David Carlisle: That's right. The end of the line was not directly visible on my screen.

Comment: @Bernard  latex has used pdftex (rather than tex) as the engine for 20 years or so.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, David. It was that local file screwing things up. I rreally appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but didn't think of checking the end of the line.

Comment: I'm seeing a warning that makes no sense to me, e.g: `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package '/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks', but the package provides 'pstricks'.` Has anyone else received this warning? If so, is there something I can do to adjust the LaTeX code to remove the warning? What should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have local (old, incompatible) versions of `xcolor.sty` and `dvips.def` in your local input tree that are being used in preference to the standard ones in the texlive 2020 tree.
Just delete those and it should all work.